# Why can't I test an Azure ML Online Endpoint even if I have the correct roles?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I have deployed an endpoint in Azure Machine Learning, but I can't test it, as apparently I don't have the correct access:
[image]

Even though I don't just have the AzureML Data Scientist role for the workspace, the endpoint and the blob storage used, but I'm actually the owner of the full resource group.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It would help in reproducing and understanding the issue if you edit question by including roles assignment snippet from Portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out when the documentation says "Give AzureML Data Scientist role to the endpoint", it doesn't mean I should give myself the AzureML Data Scientist role on the endpoint, but rather to give the *endpoint* the AzureML Data Scientist role. That fixed it.

Comment: Hey, can you please elaborate? How did you assign the AzureML Data Scientist role to the endpoint?

Comment: Adding the role to it as you would with any other managed identity. It's detailed in the docs, google them.